# How to access a Web Service hosted on a Windows Service from a client application?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio, client

Recently I developed a WCF Web Service and, with the help of internet files, I managed to host  it inside a Windows Service. I also managed to successfully install and start this Windows Service on my computer. In principle, the Web Service is working perfectly fine (debug was done); it's mission is to retrieve some data from a MySQL database located on the same computer.

Now my question is: suppose I'm on my product's client side; so now I want to develop a client application that enters in contact (to use) with my Web Service that is hosted on this Windows Service. **How should I do this? What would be the necessary configurations/procedures in order for my application to locate the web service?**

Notice that, for debug purposes, I managed to create a console debug application that successfully accessed the web service. This was done by the "add reference" menu at Visual Studio 2012 with the temporary link learned when debugging the WCF web service on its own - closed to figure 5-19 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx). The WCF WS was found as part of the studio in which my test application was included by using the URL provided by VS

```
(http://127.0.0.1:12415/LifeWS.svc)
```

. Now that the WCF WS is located inside the Windows Service, I don't know which url to use.

Here is my current Windows Service App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="LifeWSService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LifeWSBehavior" name="Lifemed.Service.LifeWSService"> <!--LifeWSService.LifeWSService-->
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:12415/Lifemed  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="LifeWSService.ILifeWS" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:12415/Lifemed" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LifeWSBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <LifeWSService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LifeWSService_LifeServices_LifeWS" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://127.0.0.1:1559/LifeWS.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LifeWSService_LifeServices_WCF_LifeWS" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://127.0.0.1:12415/LifeWS.svc</value>
      </setting>
    </LifeWSService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Note: on the code above, there is reference for another Web Service, namely a ASP.NET version of the WCF Web Service I developed.

Thanks for any help,

Momergil

--- EDIT ---
I recently managed to edit my client application and execute it in another computer (with the same base system as mine). I got, then, this exception:

[image: Console application showing the exception error]

The Portuguese line tells: "No connection could be established because the destine machine actively refused them 127.0.0.1:12415.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be {baseAddress}/{endpoint name} so for first endpoint (wsHttpBinding) its `http://127.0.0.1:12415/Lifemed/` and for Mex it would be `http://127.0.0.1:12415/Lifemed/mex`